# Getting error in render function (reactjs)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use chartist.js with my react component.I am not able to show Pie chart in my react component.

Chartist.js -> https://gionkunz.github.io/chartist-js/getting-started.html

Pie.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

    var data = {
      // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
      // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
      series: [
        [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
      ]
    };

    // Create a new line chart object where as first parameter we pass in a selector
    // that is resolving to our chart container element. The Second parameter
    // is the actual data object.
   const mychart =  new Chartist.Line('.ct-chart', data);

class Pie extends Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
          <div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth">
          {mychart}

          </div>
      </div>

    )}

}

export default Pie;
```

Parent component:

```
render(){
      return(
<div>
      <Pie/>
</div>     
  )
}
```

I am importing Pie.js inside my parent component but I am getting error saying objects should be array and not objects i.e `objects are not valid react child`. see screenshot:
[image]

Comment: I'm confused--are you using a Reactified version of Chartist, e.g., https://github.com/fraserxu/react-chartist (which appears old, but you get the idea)? If not, you can't just randomly insert arbitrary objects into the DOM.

Comment: also you will get a warning on `class="ct-chart"`. since its JavaScript, `class` is a reserved work and `className` should be used instead

Comment: also `Pie` is undefined in your first codeblock. did you mean `Chart` ?

Comment: @DaveNewton How can I add objects to DOM ? I want to use chartist.js and not react-chartist because react-chartist is just a wrapper and it does not have all features.

Comment: You could try dangerouslySet or one of its alternatives, or extend react-chartist, or mix react/JQuery, etc. Your alternatives are basically the same as with anything that isn't in react already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with the code as @azium has mentioned, first in `Reactjs`, we use `className` instead of using `class` since `class` is a reserved keyword in javascript. Secondly in the first code block, you've given the class name as `Chart` and has exported `Pie`.

So to get things up and running, firstly use [Chartist for reactjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartist), and do things as mentioned in the docs (like adding css).  Instead of `import ChartistGraph from '../index';`, you can do `import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist'`. So a working Chart component will look something like this

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist'
    var data = {
      // A labels array that can contain any sort of values
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
      // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
      series: [
        [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
      ]
    };
    var data = {
      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
      series: [
        [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
      ]
    };
    var options = {
      high: 10,
      low: -10,
      axisX: {
        labelInterpolationFnc: function(value, index) {
          return index % 2 === 0 ? value : null;
        }
      }
    };
    var type = 'Bar'
class Pie extends Component {
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <ChartistGraph data={data} options={options} type={type} />
      </div>
    )}
}
export default Pie;
```

Also add this to your parent component.

Comment: I want to use chartist.js and not react-chartist with my react component.